# C program array takes more input than it should

Tags: c, arrays

I was just playing around and i created a two D array in C of 3 rows and three columns and set a nested for loops to scan the elements.
Now, a three by three matrix has Nine elements but this code is taking 10 inputs(even the for loop is running only 9 times) How is it happening???

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
int array[3][3];
int i,j;
for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
    for(j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
        printf("i = %d j = %d\n",i,j);
        scanf(" %d ",&array[i][j]);
        printf("i = %d j = %d\n",i,j);
    }
}
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: `scanf(" %d "` --> `scanf("%d"`

Comment: Why do i have to do that?

Comment: Where is it taking the extra input? What do the `printf`s show?

Comment: before entering anything it shows i = 0 j = 0 but after entering an input it does not show anything then after that it works normally.

Comment: i = 0 j = 0
1
2
i = 0 j = 0
i = 0 j = 1
3
i = 0 j = 1
i = 0 j = 2
4
i = 0 j = 2
i = 1 j = 0
5
i = 1 j = 0
i = 1 j = 1
6
i = 1 j = 1
i = 1 j = 2
7
i = 1 j = 2
i = 2 j = 0
8
i = 2 j = 0
i = 2 j = 1
9
i = 2 j = 1
i = 2 j = 2
10
i = 2 j = 2

Comment: space after `%d` wait for not white-spaces(space, tab and newline, etc).

Comment: There's probably someone who knows more, but I think the space you have there makes it not take accept the input until you have whitespace before the number. It's not that it's getting 10 inputs, but rather `1` isn't a valid input while `1\n2` is for that string.

Comment: Thanks lluvatar and BLUEPIXY you are right the whitespace is causing the problem i'll look it up why it is happening       Thanks again it was a valuable thing to learn

Comment: Note that the space _before_ `"%d"` is not the issue - it is simply not needed as `"%d` consumes leading white-space even without the leading `" "`.

Comment: Robust code also checks the result of input functions like `scanf()`.  `if scanf(" %d ",&array[i][j] != 1) Handle_Error();`

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf(" %d " --> scanf("%d"
```

Probably , the space after **%d** results in scanf waiting for another input. So, remove the space and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%d ",&array[i][j]) ----> scanf("%d",&array[i][j])
```

this might help resolving it